# how can i remove undefined error while creating a shopping cart?

Tags: php

This here is my PHP code which is throwing the error of undefined index 'title' at line 15.

```
<?php
// connect to the database
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ecommerce");
// getting the categories
    function getCats(){
        global $con;
        $get_cats = "select * from categories";
        $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

        while ($row_cats = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
            $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];

            // Notice: Undefined index: title in D:\wamp64\www\ecommerce\functions\functions.php on line 15
            //This is the line causing the error
            $cat_title = $row_cats['title'];

            echo "<li><a href ='#'>$cat_title</a></li>";
        }
    }
?>
```

From looking at my error message,  I know the error is here:

```
$cat_title = $row_cats['title'];
```

Comment: What is your error? What line is causing it? What is your array structure? There is not enough information provided to answer this.

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: title in D:\wamp64\www\ecommerce\functions\functions.php on line 15

Comment: that is the error sir, I have tried the isset() to no avail

Comment: what happens if you do `print_r( $row_cats )`, please show me the output

Comment: Array ( [0] => 5 [cat_id] => 5 [1] => Ear Phones [cat_title] => Ear Phones )

Comment: Your problem is that your key `title` does not exist. Should it not be `$cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];`?

Comment: wow thanks a lot sir i forgot to it now works.

Comment: OK, I will post this as answer please accept.

Comment: okay sir please do

Comment: I have added my answer. Thank you for working with me to solve the issue, it is very helpful of you to provide the information I ask for.

Comment: You are welcome sir  I wish I can be as good as you in Php am a newbie

Comment: We all start somewhere, now you know for next time :) Please accept my answer below.

Comment: Thank you, sir, for accepting my answer

Comment: you're welcome do you have a platform where I can be sending you quizzes? like an e-mail or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, your array structure looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 5 [cat_id] => 5 [1] => Ear Phones [cat_title] => Ear Phones )
```

I think you've made a typo, you probably meant to do this

```
$cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];
```

instead, you did this by mistake:

```
$cat_title = $row_cats['title'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$row_cats['title'];
```

undefine index means there is not title index in the given array $row_cats. you must be getting empty when you are printing.

```
echo "<li><a href ='#'>$cat_title</a></li>";
```

what you can do to remove error you can put a condition.

```
if(isset($row_cats['title'])){
$cat_title = $row_cats['title'];
            echo "<li><a href ='#'>$cat_title</a></li>";
}
```

why I put echo part also inside my condition. because if you do not put it inside you will get another error on below line undefined variable $cat_title.

alternative you can do this

```
if(isset($row_cats['title'])){
    $cat_title = $row_cats['title'];
}
                echo "<li><a href ='#'>";
if(isset($cat_title)){ echo $cat_title; }
echo "</a></li>";
```